# Confusion on pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm learning C and now I'm having confusion in pointers. My question is, why doesn't printf("%d", *(i)); return the element instead of address while using multidimensional array??

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i[2][2] = {{1,8},{2,9},{3, 4}};
    //int i[2] = {1,2,3};
    printf("%d", *(i));
    printf("\n%d", i);
}
```

Comment: Please note also that in your code, `i` has length 2 but the initializer has 3 elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it's an array of arrays, so indexing/dereferencing it once gives you an array, which decays to a pointer...

Comment: Yes, and image in this article should explain it further: http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx9b.html

Comment: @dbrank0: That page you are linking to is about "simulated multi-dimensional arrays" through several levels of pointer arrays. This is something different than the "normal" multidimensional array we have here. Thus, the picture is not really correct for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Because a multidimensional array is can be written as **i so you doing *(i) gives you the address of the first array.